# Computed column does not include one of the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a computed column in order to have a unique index on a nullable column that ignores NULL rows<sup>1</sup>. I've composed this test case:

```
SELECT TEST_ID, CODE, UNIQUE_CODE, CAST(UNIQUE_CODE AS VARBINARY(4000)) AS HEX
FROM (
    SELECT TEST_ID, CODE,
    ISNULL(CODE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, SPACE(10)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, TEST_ID)) AS UNIQUE_CODE
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS TEST_ID, 'ABCDEFGHIJ' AS CODE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'XYZ'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, NULL
    ) TEST
) X;
```

It works as expected when `CODE` is not null but I only get a string of whitespaces when `CODE` is null (i.e., the trailing `TEST_ID` is missing):

```
TEST_ID | CODE       | UNIQUE_CODE | HEX
--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------
      1 | ABCDEFGHIJ | ABCDEFGHIJ  | 0x4142434445464748494A
      2 |  XYZ       | XYZ         | 0x58595A
      3 | NULL       |             | 0x20202020202020202020
```

The funny thing is that I already use this technique successfully in another table and I can't spot the difference:

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_OTHER_TABLE (
    SOME_OTHER_TABLE_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),

    -- This works just fine:
    NOMBRE_UNICO AS ISNULL(NOMBRE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, SPACE(50)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SOME_OTHER_TABLE_ID)),

    CONSTRAINT SOME_OTHER_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (SOME_OTHER_TABLE_ID)
);
```

What am I missing?

*(<sup>1</sup>) This was a workaround for SQL Server 2005 that's no longer necessary in later versions thanks to filtered indexes.*

Comment: You should explicitly define size/length for all varchar conversions and constant values.

Comment: "in order to have a unique index on a nullable column that ignores NULL rows". Why not do `create index [idxName] on [yourTable] (Code) where Code IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @BenThul Because I had no idea you could do that. None of the docs I found said so and some suggested the complicate workaround I'm using...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Filtered indexes were added in SQL 2008, so you should be good to go. A lot fewer moving parts than you've got going here.

Comment: @BenThul I've just tried filtered indexes and got rid of my workaround. App was started on SQL Server 2005 but that's no longer an excuse. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go with `"          3"`

```
SELECT TEST_ID, CODE, UNIQUE_CODE, CAST(UNIQUE_CODE AS VARBINARY(4000)) AS HEX
FROM (
    SELECT TEST_ID, CODE,
    ISNULL(CODE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SPACE(10)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TEST_ID)) AS UNIQUE_CODE
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS TEST_ID, cast('ABCDEFGHIJ' as varchar(20)) AS CODE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'XYZ'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, NULL
    ) TEST
) X;
```

[image]

`'ABCDEFGHIJ'` (first value in the union list) is exactly 10 characters and this column is a first argument of IsNull. So it takes 10 characters as size for IsNull result. Which is enough only for spaces. Replacing this constant with `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'` would do the trick also.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check if I can make it work with an actual table (`CODE` is actually a `VARCHAR(10)` column) and I'll report back.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Just a note: when `CODE` is a real column you need to convert inside `ISNULL()`, e.g.: `ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CODE), ...`.

Comment: Yes, sure. Since there would be no `union` and subquery.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SQL is trying to help out to define the column length in your inner query.  By casting/converting to a specific size this fixes the problem.  Once your `UNIQUE_CODE` field exceeds this value, the returned value is limited to the size of the column.

```
SELECT TEST_ID, CODE, UNIQUE_CODE, CAST(UNIQUE_CODE AS VARBINARY(4000)) AS HEX
FROM (
    SELECT TEST_ID, CODE,
    ISNULL(CODE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, SPACE(10)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, TEST_ID)) AS UNIQUE_CODE
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS TEST_ID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'ABCDEFGHIJ') AS CODE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'XYZ'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, NULL
    ) TEST
) X;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run below piece of code to find out why ?

this fails :

```
declare @a char(20)
set @a=null

declare @b char(10)
set @b='aaaaaa'

select isnull(@a,convert(char(10),space(10)+@b))
```

This works:

```
declare @a char(20)
set @a=null

declare @b char(10)
set @b='aaaaaa'

select isnull(@a,convert(char(30),space(10)+@b))
```